# Copy ctor on return by value C++11

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, return-by-value

Is copy ctor needed for return-by-value in c++11 when there exists a move constructor? GCC 4.7.1 complains that the copy-ctor is implicity deleted since I only have a move constructor but I thought it should use the move constructor in this case.

```
VeryLargeObject foo(...)
    {
    VeryLargeObject ret;
    //Built object
    return ret; //<Error: VeryLargeObject has deleted copy-constructor
    }
```

I do not want to add the copy-constructor until I really need it.

EDIT:

Sorry I found that I forgot the move constructor... I only had move assignment :-(

Comment: It _can_ be moved, but I believe a copy constructor must still be available. That's in case the compiler decides to use it, which it may.

Comment: As far as I understand, the compiler is allowed to use RVO or, failing that, move the object. It probably won't make a copy unless both RVO and move are impossible. But even though it *can* use those optimizations, in the end it's still copy semantics so it requires a copy constructor even if it's not actually used. If your copy constructor is deleted, use `std::move` to enforce moving.

Comment: Tried to find this rule in 12.8 quickly, but ran of time. 12.8/31 may have it if you can be bothered to parse it. Or possibly 12.2, which talks about the temporary that is created for `return` (and then possibly elided).

Comment: I assume this warning is being issued erroneously in GCC-4.7.1, [I can't reproduce it in GCC-4.7.3](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=81c875b0220700e05378232ed5ad5691-2438b4e957c5420b0a260e73b49338a6).

Comment: I tried on gcc 4.8.1 and msvc120 and they don't complain about the private copy ctor

Comment: Yeah it could just be a partial-support thing...

Comment: @syam I tried std::move but got the same thing.

Comment: @syam: `std::move` absolutely does not "enforce" moving. All it does is procure an rvalue ref. It is [very] badly named in that regard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Right, bad choice of words on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should only require a move constructor in this situation.  Either your code has a bug (perhaps the move constructor was suppressed, or you didn't actually add it) or it's a GCC bug.  It looks like based on your post edit, it was probably the former.

A copy constructor *would* be needed if you tried to return an L-value other than a local variable.  In that situation, you can turn an L-value into an R-value using `move()` to get it to work (realizing that you will then probably be changing the state of the L-value, of course).